# jQuery Selectmenu with Rails grouped_collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, select-menu

I have been playing around with the jQuery-ui Selectmenu, but haven't been able to get it to work with the `grouped_collection_select`. The Selectmenu works with the basic select when I set the class to "selectmenu," which I have set the jQuery-ui to look for. Basically, I'm struggling to add Class to `grouped_collection_select`.

I have tried:
`<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:state_id, Country.order(:id), :categories, :name, :id, :name, {:include_blank=>true, :class=>"selectmenu"})%>`

and
`<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:state_id, Country.order(:id), :categories, :name, :id, :name, :class=>"selectmenu")%>`

I was able to add the class using $('#user_state_id).addClass('selectmenu') in my coffeescript. However, this seemed to cause my dynamic menu from being able to update the options for my State select menu.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here? Is there a better way to set the class for grouped_collection_select. I've checked the source code and the class is not being added using :class=> in `grouped_collection_select`.

The selectmenu: 
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grouped_collection_select` takes nine arguments. If you are passing object in with the `f` it only takes eight arguments.

The last argument is `html_options`, where you need to place the `class`.  This will get you the `class` on the `select` form field element but not `optgroup` or `option` elements.

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:state_id, Country.order(:id), :categories, :name, :id, :name, { :include_blank => true }, { :class=> "selectmenu" }) %>
```

Without the `:include_blank => true` it would look like this:

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select(:state_id, Country.order(:id), :categories, :name, :id, :name, {}, { :class=> "selectmenu" }) %>
```

Which should get you:

```
<select class="selectmenu" id="object_state_id" name="object[state_id]">...
```